# TypeError when loading saved search

Tags: typeerror, suitescript2.0, saved-searches

I keep running into this error when I try to load a saved search. "TypeError Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'load')". I'm relatively new to SuiteScript. I don't see what I'm doing wrong when loading the saved search. Any suggestions would be welcomed.

I'm trying to do a field validation using `validateField` in a Client Script.

Here is my code:

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.0
 * @NScriptType ClientScript
 */
define(['N/search'],
/**
* @param {search} search
*/
function(search) {
    
    /**
     * Function to be executed after page is initialized.
     *
     * @param {Object} scriptContext
     * @param {Record} scriptContext.currentRecord - Current form record
     * @param {string} scriptContext.mode - The mode in which the record is being accessed (create, copy, or edit)
     *
     * @since 2015.2
     */
    function pageInit(scriptContext) {

    }

    /**
     * Function to be executed when field is changed.
     *
     * @param {Object} scriptContext
     * @param {Record} scriptContext.currentRecord - Current form record
     * @param {string} scriptContext.sublistId - Sublist name
     * @param {string} scriptContext.fieldId - Field name
     * @param {number} scriptContext.lineNum - Line number. Will be undefined if not a sublist or matrix field
     * @param {number} scriptContext.columnNum - Line number. Will be undefined if not a matrix field
     *
     * @since 2015.2
     */
    function fieldChanged(context) {
 
    }
    /**
     * Function to be executed when field is slaved.
     *
     * @param {Object} scriptContext
     * @param {Record} scriptContext.currentRecord - Current form record
     * @param {string} scriptContext.sublistId - Sublist name
     * @param {string} scriptContext.fieldId - Field name
     *
     * @since 2015.2
     */
    function postSourcing(scriptContext) {

    }

    /**
     * Function to be executed after sublist is inserted, removed, or edited.
     *
     * @param {Object} scriptContext
     * @param {Record} scriptContext.currentRecord - Current form record
     * @param {string} scriptContext.sublistId - Sublist name
     *
     * @since 2015.2
     */
    function sublistChanged(scriptContext) {

    }

    /**
     * Function to be executed after line is selected.
     *
     * @param {Object} scriptContext
     * @param {Record} scriptContext.currentRecord - Current form record
     * @param {string} scriptContext.sublistId - Sublist name
     *
     * @since 2015.2
     */
    function lineInit(scriptContext) {

    }

    /**
     * Validation function to be executed when field is changed.
     *
     * @param {Object} scriptContext
     * @param {Record} scriptContext.currentRecord - Current form record
     * @param {string} scriptContext.sublistId - Sublist name
     * @param {string} scriptContext.fieldId - Field name
     * @param {number} scriptContext.lineNum - Line number. Will be undefined if not a sublist or matrix field
     * @param {number} scriptContext.columnNum - Line number. Will be undefined if not a matrix field
     *
     * @returns {boolean} Return true if field is valid
     *
     * @since 2015.2
     */
    function validateField(context,search) {
        debugger;
        var custPmt = context.currentRecord;
        
        if(context.fieldId == 'memo' ) {
            var memoValue = custPmt.getValue('memo');
            
            var objSearch = search.load({
                id: 'customsearch51957'
            
            });

               //add filter
               var filter = search.createFilter({
               name: 'memo',
               operator: search.Operator.IS,
               values: memoValue
               });

               objSearch.filters.push(filter);
          
            var searchResults = objSearch.run().getRange({
                start : 0,
                end   : 10
            });
               var resultsCount = searchResults.length;

               if(resultsCount > 0) {
                   alert(memoValue + " record already exists.");
                   return false;
               }
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Validation function to be executed when sublist line is committed.
     *
     * @param {Object} scriptContext
     * @param {Record} scriptContext.currentRecord - Current form record
     * @param {string} scriptContext.sublistId - Sublist name
     *
     * @returns {boolean} Return true if sublist line is valid
     *
     * @since 2015.2
     */
    function validateLine(scriptContext) {

    }

    /**
     * Validation function to be executed when sublist line is inserted.
     *
     * @param {Object} scriptContext
     * @param {Record} scriptContext.currentRecord - Current form record
     * @param {string} scriptContext.sublistId - Sublist name
     *
     * @returns {boolean} Return true if sublist line is valid
     *
     * @since 2015.2
     */
    function validateInsert(scriptContext) {

    }

    /**
     * Validation function to be executed when record is deleted.
     *
     * @param {Object} scriptContext
     * @param {Record} scriptContext.currentRecord - Current form record
     * @param {string} scriptContext.sublistId - Sublist name
     *
     * @returns {boolean} Return true if sublist line is valid
     *
     * @since 2015.2
     */
    function validateDelete(scriptContext) {

    }

    /**
     * Validation function to be executed when record is saved.
     *
     * @param {Object} scriptContext
     * @param {Record} scriptContext.currentRecord - Current form record
     * @returns {boolean} Return true if record is valid
     *
     * @since 2015.2
     */
    function saveRecord(scriptContext) {

    }

    return {
//        pageInit: pageInit,
//        fieldChanged: fieldChanged,
//        postSourcing: postSourcing,
//        sublistChanged: sublistChanged,
//        lineInit: lineInit,
        validateField: validateField
//        validateLine: validateLine,
//        validateInsert: validateInsert,
//        validateDelete: validateDelete,
//        saveRecord: saveRecord
    };
    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that I only need to pass the search object to the callback function and not in the `validateField` function.